# How can I start pagination at new line? I'm using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

As you see the image. The result of pagination comes right next to the shops list.
It has to be below that.
How can I do that?

**view**

```
<div class='pagination-centered'>
    <%= page_entries_info(@shops).html_safe %>
    <%= paginate @shops, :window => 4, :outer_window => 5, :left => 2, :right => 2 %>
</div>


<% @shops.each do |shop| %>  
    <%= render 'shops/shop', :shop => shop %>
<% end %>


<div class='pagination-centered'>
    <%= paginate @shops, :window => 4, :outer_window => 5, :left => 2, :right => 2 %>
    <%= page_entries_info(@shops).html_safe %>
```

**Image**

[image]

**UPDATE:** This is the HTML that is generated. pagination has to be started at new line.
It shouldn't be at the same line as Shops.

```
<div class='pagination-centered'>
    Displaying <b>all 4</b> shops
</div>  

<span class='shop'>
    <div class="List">
        …shop A...                      
    </div>


    <div class="List">
        …shop B...                      
    </div>

    <div class="List">
        …shop C...                      
    </div>
</span>


<div class='pagination-centered'>
    Displaying <b>all 4</b> shops
</div>
```

Comment: maybe its just me but i dont see anything on your image, i mean the problem you mentioned.
if you want to place under it, maybe its a float problem, hard to tell with the details you provided, please be more specific with the image and your code

Comment: @LeventeNagy Thanks. I updated my Question. Could you please check it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your span or list contain a float thats the problem

try

```
<div class='pagination-centered'>
    Displaying <b>all 4</b> shops
</div>  

<span class='shop'>
    <div class="List">
        …shop A...                      
    </div>


    <div class="List">
        …shop B...                      
    </div>

    <div class="List">
        …shop C...                      
    </div>
</span>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class='pagination-centered'>
    Displaying <b>all 4</b> shops
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's fine now. Is it usual to use <div class="clearfix"></div> often in codes?

Comment: A clearfix is a way for an element to automatically clear after itself, so that you don't need to add additional markup. It's generally used in float layouts where elements are floated to be stacked horizontally.

The clearfix is a way to combat the zero-height container problem for floated elements

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that using clearfix prevents SEO. Thanks anyways

Comment: @cat: I don't think CSS influence SEO directly, javascript could, but I think net crawlers completely ignore CSS **and** Javascript, they consider HTML only, so there is where you should look for if you are not going up in ranking.